# How to assign array variable as a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash, key

I'm trying to print this hash. As `key1` is the `array[0]`, `key2` is `array[2]` and `$sum[0]` is the value. But the has does not work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
@array=(10,45,20);

@sum=($array[0]+$array[1]+$array[2]);

%hash;

$hash{$array[0]}{$array[2]}=$sum[0]
```

At the end of the hashes I want to print `10 : 75` to the screen.

Comment: Please always add `use strict; use warnings;` to your scripts to avoid common errors. /// What exactly is your problem? You created a hash that contains `{ '10' => { '20' => 75 } }`. What do want instead?

Comment: at the end of the hashes I want to print   10 : 75 to the screen but I don't know how to give the referance for this hash..

Comment: Then why do you use a 2-dimensional hash at all? Why not simply `$hash{$array[0]}=$sum[0]`? That gives `{ '10' => 75 }`.

Comment: yeah I know that .I taking values from a text and put an array.Then making this array a two dimensional hash with two key which first element of the array is first key and second element as second key .Then I'm gonna print it .That's what I'm trying to do ..

Comment: Welcome to the world of computer programming!
---
As you may have noticed Borodin and ikegami have tried to help you out on an incomplete problem description. Usually these two people are excellent in understanding the problem from half questions and are willing to take you through steps to clarify things.
---
And I am stupid enough to give it another try - and I know ***not*** better than them!!!

Comment: In case you accidentally created this account in addition to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881692/fatih-teke) then please [follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description you gave to @ikegami «my program will accept ...» I created a file that would have the data:

*data_1.txt*:

```
john 10 45 20
alex 30 15 12
pete 23 45 10 21
will 06 56
bob   8 12  3
lazy
```

note that only the first two lines actually match the description, I'll come back to that later.

*sum.pl*:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'sum';

# get the two filenames it should work with
#
my $filename_1 = shift;
my $filename_2 = shift;

# be sure we read a file for most modern systems, UTF-8
#
open( my $file1, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename_1)
    or die "Can't open file: $filename_1";

# create the (empty) data structure
#
my %sums_and_names;
#
# the % in perl means you are talking about a hash,
# use a sensible name instead of 'hash'

# read line by line
while ( my $line = <$file1> ) {

    chomp $line; # get rid of the line endings
    my ($name, @grades) = split ' ', $line;
    #
    # this is not strictly doing what you asked for, just more flexible
    #
    # split on ' ', a space character, splits on any asmount of (white) space
    # your task said that there is one space.
    # strictly, you could should split on / /, the regular expression
    #
    # the first part will go into the variable $name, the rest in array @grades
    # strictly you have only three grades so the following would do
    # my ($name, $grade_1, $grade_2, $grade_3) = split / /, $line;

    my $sum = sum(@grades) // 'no grades';
    #
    # since we now can handle any number of grades, not just three, we could
    # have no grades at all and thus result in `undef`
    #
    # using the function sum0 would return the value 0 instead
    #
    # you'll get away with the `undef` using in a hash assignment,
    # it will turn it into an empty string `''`

=pod

    $sums_and_names{foo}{bar} = [ 'baz', 'qux' ];

=cut

    #
    # here is where your task doesn't make sense
    # i am guessing:
    #
    $sums_and_names{$sum}{$name} = \@grades;
    #
    # at least we have all the data from filename_1, and the sum of the grades

}

# please decide on what you want to print

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%sums_and_names;
```

and running `perl sum.pl data_1.txt data_2.txt` will give you something like

*output*:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'no grades' => {
                    'lazy' => []
                         },
          '23' => {
                    'bob'  => [
                                '8',
                                '12',
                                '3'
                              ]
                  },
          '57' => {
                    'alex' => [
                                '30',
                                '15',
                                '12'
                              ]
                  },
          '62' => {
                    'will' => [
                                '06',
                                '56'
                              ]
                  },
          '75' => {
                    'john' => [
                                '10',
                                '45',
                                '20'
                              ]
                  },
          '99' => {
                    'pete' => [
                                 '23',
                                 '45',
                                 '10',
                                 '21'
                               ]
                   }
        };
```

please note, strictly the block inside the while loop could had been written as:

```
    chomp $line;
    my ($name, $grade_1, $grade_2, $grade_3) = split / /, $line;
    $sum = $grade_1 + $grade_2 + $grade_3;
    $sums_and_names{$sum}{$name} = [ $grade_1, $grade_2, $grade_3 ];
```

but I quote from @Borodin:

> And while I'm sure you want something more general than that, you really haven't given enough information

Comment: You don't use `$filename_2`. I don't think it makes a difference, though. It's totally unclear what data structure the OP really wants and his comments don't help either. I, for example, now think the structure he asks for is `$sums_and_names{$name}{$sum}` (keys swapped). We just don't know. He should show the desired output (in a Data::Dumper or JSON format), but he refuses that.

Comment: of course I know I was not using `$filename_2`, but that is what it said in his last description "... accept two unsorted files." --- I intentionally left it there and tried to show that it is a badly described question and that the OP should rethink how he asks it next time. --- I could actually have added some checking that one did pass in two filenames

Comment: yeah that's work my document exactly similar with it.Sorry I could't share the code because I couldn't have the permission for it.I just couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong and with your example I got it .Thank you .I was giving hash references not a value.

Answer (score 2):

You've set

```
$hash{$array[0]}{$array[2]} = $sum[0]
```

which with the given values is

```
$hash{10}{20} = 75
```

If you want to print `10 : 75` from the hash then you need to write

```
printf "%d : %d\n",10, $hash{10}{20}
```

And while I'm sure you want something more general than that, you really haven't given enough information

Comment: yes I can do like that but I want to use this for big files so I can't write hashes like that I have to write like array[1] and array[2] for keys ... how can I take it like that.. ?

Comment: think like that I have a file that contains     chris 10 34 56    values .And I want take tehm as an array then make two dimensinol hash with two key.As chris=first key and sum of the numbers=second key then ı want to print chris=sum of tree numbers ..

Comment: @Fatih: Yes, I imagined that you had more than one line of data, but your example is overly trivial. If you show only one line then we can't see how it's supposed to scale. Please show several more lines of data together with the corresponding output that you want. If the send key `20` is never used then there's no reason to store it in the hash.

Comment: @Faith: You really need to explain why you think you need `$array[2]` as a hash key at all. In your code, the sum of the numbers is the *hash value*, and it looks like you need only one key.

Comment: yes I can keep values with one key either but I want to keep with two key .. I'm already done with the one key ..

Comment: my program will accept two unsorted files. Each file contains 4 columns separated by space. The first column is the name(string). Rest of the columns (3 columns) are integers representing the grades. Load the first file into a two-dimensional hash data structure with the sum of the integers(total grade) as the second dimension key and the name

Comment: @Fatih: What's that, your homework question? You *still need to explain* why you want to use the sum as a second hash key, and now we don't know what the value should be. You won't get better answers if you don't explain things better. Please *edit your question* to add information instead of putting it into comments.

Comment: I need second hash key because after done with the one key ı'm gonna extend the file like the same name same sum but different values..If I do that with the one key they will be all same keys but result should be different right?

Comment: @Fatih: Wrong. But it's impossible to tell what your real requirement is because you just won't give us any information. I'm voting to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!
- There's only one sum (at a time), so don't need an array.
- There's no need for a hash of hash; a simple hash will do.

Fixed:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use List::Util qw( sum );


my %hash;
while (...) {
   my @nums = ...;
   $hash{ $nums[0] } = sum(@nums);
}

for (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%hash)) {
   print("$_: $hash{$_}\n");
}
```

Comment: thank for interest but I already did with one key also I want to create with two key .. your code just have one key ..

Comment: As it should. There's no point in creating a more complicated data structure than needed.

Comment: chris
: HASH(0x5581f6193078)     my output seems like that I'm writing the same why getting me the hash result..

Comment: my program will accept two unsorted files. Each file contains  4 columns separated by space. The first column is the name(string). Rest of the columns (3 columns) are integers representing the grades. Load the first file into a two-dimensional hash data structure with the sum of the integers(total grade) as the second dimension key and the name

Comment: If there's a problem with your question, fix it. Feel free to let me know when you've done that by leaving a comment here.